# Parameters are not getting subsituted in MyBatis query

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, mybatis

The following is my select query in BrandMapper.xml.

```
<select id="getBrand" parameterType="String" resultMap="brandResult">
    SELECT 
        B.bid as bid, 
        B.bname as bname, 
        B.avg_price as avg_price, 
        B.total_number as total_number, 
        P.pid as pid, 
        P.pname as pname, 
        P.bid as pbid, 
        P.bname as pbname, 
        P.specs as pspecs, 
        P.price as price 
    from Brands B left outer join Products P on P.bid = B.bid 
    where B.bname = #{bname, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
</select>
```

This is the interface

```
public interface BrandMapper {
    BrandDAO getBrand(String bname);
}
```

This is the service class

```
@Service
public class BrandService {
@Autowired
private BrandMapper brandMapper;
public BrandDAO getBrand(String bname) {
    System.out.println("Inside DBService getBrand");
    return brandMapper.getBrand(bname);
}
}
```

My problem is that the `getBrand` function in `BrandService` returns a `null` value. If I replace the parameter `#{bname}` inside the `BrandMapper.xml` by a hardcoded string it works and returns the correct class. What am I doing wrong here? Is there any logs or anything available where I can see the actual query which is being constructed? Any help is appreciated.

I managed to enable loggin using log4j and this is the query which is getting executed

```
SELECT B.bid as bid, B.bname as bname, B.avg_price as avg_price, B.total_number as total_number, P.pid as pid, P.pname as pname, P.bid as pbid, P.bname as pbname, P.specs as pspecs, P.price as price from Brands B left outer join Products P on P.bid = B.bid where B.bname = ?
```

The parameter is not getting replaced. I cant figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Just a side note: Isn't DAO used wrong here? By convention, DAO should be the class that provides the methods to retrieve database mapped objects, not the object itself, right?

Answer (score 3):

The question mark is a placeholder in Prepared Statements, the logged query is perfectly fine and looks as expected. The real value should be passed along the query to your database as a separate parameter.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Actually the error was not in mybatis, it was in a top layer. The parameters passed to mybatis (i.e. brandmapper.getBrand) itself was null. On a different note shouldnt mybatis be doing some validation checks for it because it knows it is expecting a parameter and its getting a null value? Could have saved a lot of my time.

Comment: @n3o Null value can be a valid one if the db column is empty.